# Can make shell run interactively along with --command option

Tags: linux, git, bash, shell

I'm using [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Invoking-Bash) that is installed as git bash. On startup I need to change directory, so I'm doing it like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" --rcfile "./cd.sh"
```

Where `cd.sh` just contains `cd /d/` command. Everything works fine here. Now I'm trying to get rid of `cd.sh` file and pass command to the shell as a parameter yet I want it to remain interactive, so I'm doing like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" -ic "cd /d"
```

It executes the command (tested with `echo` command) but then exits. Why doesn't it stay interactive?

Comment: Just use your normal shell initialization script? (i.e. `.bashrc` or similar... with appropriate guards on `SHLVL`, etc. to make sure you only do it once.) Or try changing directory before launching `sh`?

Comment: @EtanReisner, thanks, as I understand from @Julien Lopez answer, `c` and `i` option won't work together, right?

Answer (score 1):

From [man bash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> An interactive shell is one started without non-option arguments and without the -c option ...

From [man dash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dash):

> If no args are present and if the standard input of the shell is connected to a terminal (or if the -i flag is set), and the -c option is not present, the shell is considered an interactive shell.

Comment: so what you're saying `-c` and `-i` don't make sense when used together?

Comment: Yep. You won't have an interactive shell if you use `-c`. As @EtanReisner suggested, you could add your command in your `.bashrc` if your goal is to open a terminal on another directory than just `~`.